# How to generate asp.net textbox accoring to the digit displays in label text?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If in the label the default text is 10 then ten textbox controls will be generated in webform ...

Can anybody did this in VB.NET ?

Comment: This is a very unclear question.  You want to know how to generate 10 text boxes based on a numeric value in a label?

Comment: YA....i have to generate 10 txtboxes or more according to the numeric value in label text .. !! 

But i want asp.net ... Controls with VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at add control.
You simply use a loop based on the counter in the label then you say myWebForm.Controls.Add(txtBox); where txtBox is:

```
Dim txtBox as TextBox
```

Sure here is some code:

```
Dim count as Integer

count =  CType(Me.myLabel.Text, Integer)

For i as Integer=0 to count-1
  txtBox = new TextBox()
  txtBox.ID = "txt" & i.ToString()
  myForm.Controls.Add(txtBox)
Next i
```

Comment: CAn u provide me the coding 4 that, because m the fresher in ASP.Net (VB)